# Single Source Qualifier column into multiple columns

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a comma separated value (csv) file which needs to be loaded into a table, using Informatica. First column contains a concatenated value, concatenated by a '~', which needs to be saved into 7 different columns.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four ways i think you can do but all has pros and cons.

1. First read using a Source Qualifier with ~ as delimiter and write it into a csv file. So now you have all columns are delimited by comma. Then use this file as source to your next process. Pro - easy process. cons - two step process so can take time. Also if your data has ,/~ you need to enclose them using "".
2. Use shell script to replace ~ with comma. So now you have all columns are delimited by comma Then use this file as source to your next process. cons - Script need to be careful not to replace ~ inside data.
3. You can use one source qualifier(read file as comma separated) and the split the first column into 7 parts using INSTR/SUBSTR combination.
   Step1 - first find position of ~ in first column like this -

```
v_pos1 = InStr( col1, '~', 1, 1)
v_pos2 = InStr( col1, '~', 1, 2)
v_pos3 = InStr( col1, '~', 1, 3)
...
```

Step 2 -

```
o_val1 = iif(v_pos1 =0,col1, SubStr( col1, 1, v_pos1 - 1))
o_val2 = iif(v_pos2 =0,'', SubStr( col1, v_pos1 + 1), SubStr( col1, v_pos1 + 1, v_pos2 - v_pos1 - 1))
o_val2 = iif(v_pos2 =0,'', SubStr( col1, v_pos2 + 1), SubStr( col1, v_pos2 + 1, v_pos3 - v_pos2 - 1))
...
```

4. You can also use new created `LOOP` transformation. This is an extension and need some bit of research

Comment: I'd just add to point 2: you can set the source qualifier session property named `input type` to command and then use `sed` to replace `~` to commas. This is basically the same thing, but does the trick at read time, so no additional file will be created. Still, you need to be careful if it's possible to have `~` in other columns.